# Handling network issues while uploading files

Tags: java, javascript, html, gwt, file-upload

Here is the html generated so far (Using `GWT`  as front end) , what I have so far  which replicates the GWT [FileUpload](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FileUpload.html) class.

```
<input type="file" id="input" onchange="handleFiles(this.file)">
```

works fine with help of `HandleFileUploadServet.java`, since java as backend.

To handle that  using  `addSubmitCompleteHandler`

```
form.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new SubmitCompleteHandler() {..
```

Which is equivalent to

```
 .submit(function(){
   //handle file response
})
```

Works fine.

Here is the problem ,While uploading the file If  internet disconnect,There is no  `error/exception/response` thrown by browser.

I want to inform user that,There is a network issue.

But browser keep submitting the form and not returning from that state.

Any hints ?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Do check in your handler if the event is null?

```
form.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new FormPanel.SubmitCompleteHandler() {
        public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event) {
            if(event != null){
                   Window.alert("Upload OK!");
            }else
                   Window.alert("Upload fail");
    });
```

But I think that SubmitCompleteEvent is never fired if you have network issues.

A Solution can be to make a timer when you submit the file :

```
public class ViewWidget {

Form form;
Timer timer = new Timer() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         Window.alert("Troubles with upload! Try again!");
     }
 };

 public ViewWidget(){
     form.addSubmitHandler(new SubmitHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSubmit(SubmitEvent event) {
            timer.schedule(10000);
        }
    });

     form.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new SubmitCompleteHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event) {
            //Cancel the timer
            timer.cancel();

            if(event != null){
                //Do your Stuff
                Window.alert("Upload Ok !");
            }else
                Window.alert("Upload Fails");
        }
    });
 }
```

I don't try the code but it should work.

Hope it helps.